# Action Polling is not understood in BizTalk

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, biztalk

I have an orchestration set up using the Consume SQL Adapter in BizTalk. As shown in the Orchestration, I have a Request/Response Send Port. I have set the inbound process on my SQL Adapter as so:

Send Port
[image: Send Port]

Orchestration
[image: Orchestration]

On the Send WDF-Custom sql-bindings, I did not set the Action text box, but set the inbound properties on the binding configuration, for the Send Request/Response port,  the same as the Receive Port. When I start it up and move my message request file to the Receive directory, I get the following error:

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "SNDPortTwoWay" with URL "mssql://DESKTOP-T2G7B3A//AFBizTalkTest?InboundId=MyID". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.UnsupportedOperationException: The action "Polling" was not understood.

Not sure where this is coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a one way receive location for polling, not a two way send port.

If you want a request response send port you either have to use a table operation or a stored procedure call, in which case you have to use the WCF Consume Adapter Service to create the appropriate schema, and it will also create the port binding for you, and you can import that into the BizTalk Admin Console, and then give it a nicer name.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I built a new orchestration, with a Receive message and a Send message, configured my SQL Adapter for Inbound (polling), set my polling statements, ie. check for data, retrieve data and it worked!!